# log4net web plugin location of log file

Tags: log4net

I have a windows forms application that runs in two different modes desktop mode and web plugin mode. I'm trying to put the log files using log4net in the same place. but when it is running as a web plugin my log file get put into the temporary internet folder of the users app data folder.

Code:

```
 Uri uri = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);

 if (Uri.TryCreate(uri, "log4net.config", out uri))
 {
     log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(uri.LocalPath));
 }

_configured = true;

if (Utilities.WebPlugin)
{
    var logNetHierarchy = (log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
    foreach (var iAppender in logNetHierarchy.Root.Appenders)
    {
      if (iAppender is FileAppender)
      {
          var fileAppender = (FileAppender)iAppender;

          fileAppender.File = @"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\Company\Viewer\Web\log.xml";

          fileAppender.ActivateOptions();
       }
    } 
}
```

I would like to get them in the same place without including some kind of script.

Comment: Your code looks like it should work - does the web plugin have sufficient privileges to write to c:\users?

Comment: It creates the folder correctly in desktop mode. How do I check the permissions in web plugin mode?

Comment: What **is** web plugin mode?

Comment: Basically the application is a media type using the <object>.

Comment: Doesn't that mean it's running in a sandbox, without filesystem access?

Comment: Interesting question. I need to learn more about that. But would it even write the log file at all if that was the case?

Answer (score 0):

stuartd was right soon as I put the site into trusted sites it worked perfectly.